# ffmpeg error with SIGSEGV

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, video

ffmpeg was killed with signal SIGSEGV (using fluent-ffmpeg in nodejs on ubuntu)

I am expecting ffmpeg to take a provided url and timestamps, then trim the video down. Once that happens I want it to output the video to the same directory as the code so my other code can work with it!

problem is that on .saveToFile I get the ffmpeg was killed with signal SIGSEGV error. Im running an ubuntu server on a local machine on my local network.

```
ffmpeg() .input(url) .outputOptions('-ss', timeSTART, '-to', timeEND) .saveToFile(vidID) .on('progress', (progress) => { if (progress.percent) { // console.log(process.memoryUsage.toString()); console.log(`Processing: ${Math.floor(progress.percent)}% done`); } })
```

Comment: what version of ffmpeg and fluent-ffmpeg and nodejs do you have

Comment: actually figured out that it had to do with the path to ffmpeg

inside of the node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js

go and change command to = the path to the top level ffmpeg instead of the node_modules ffmpeg and it works like a charm!